# Moment .JS - Why is the difference not in full year format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

For the following JavaScript, I was expecting output to be 1 but it is not, any explanation?

```
var startDate = moment('2018-01-01');
var endDate = moment('2018-12-31');

moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate)).asYears()

0.9965981505438167
```

What start and end dates would give 1 full year?

Comment: Start `'2018-01-01'` and end `'2019-01-01'`?

Comment: @VLAZ still not full year - 0.9993360575508053

Comment: Yeah, just tried it now. Bizarre. I got a full year with `startDate = moment('2018-01-01T10:00:00')` and `endDate = moment('2019-01-01T15:49:12')`. So, does Moment count *all* the hours of the year? Including the ones that we use "stash" into daylight savings? I've not double-checked but it but 5:49 should be pretty close to what the extra hours every year are. The ones we turn into an extra day every 4 years but not if it's a century, unless it's a century that is divisible by 400.

Answer (score 1):

It is because diff gives you the differences in milliseconds and then recalculated in years, giving you the 0.99.. value

In order to get a difference in years you can do this:

```
endDate.diff(startDate, 'year');
```

and you will get 1 as wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe you can understand.

```
var startDate = moment("2018-01-01").startOf("day");
var endDate = moment("2019-01-01").startOf("day");
// var endDate = moment("2018-12-31").startOf("day");  try this also.
console.log(startDate);
console.log(endDate);
console.log("--------------");
console.log(endDate.diff(startDate, "days"));
console.log(endDate.diff(startDate, "years"));
console.log("--------------");
```